# How To Google "Docs" API BatchUpdate in javascript (Code Required)

Tags: javascript, google-docs-api

I have Use Following Code For Insert Text In Google Docs. But Its Not Work.
Google Also Not provided any single example in JavaScript for batchupdate. anyone knows about that thing?

```
  function makeApiCall() {
      var updateObject = {
          documentId: 'My-Document-Id',
          resource: {
              requests: [{
                  "insertText": {
                      "text": "Sameer Bayani",
                      "location": {
                          "index": 25,
                      },
                  },
              }],
          },
      };
      gapi.client.docs.documents.batchUpdate(updateObject, function (e, r) {
          if (e) {
              console.log(e);
          } else {
              console.log(r.data);
          }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Describe what does not work. Do you see any errors (using F12 tools for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- I think that your request body is correct.

  - But I used `1` as `index` of `location` as a test. In this case, the text can be also inserted to new Document. Because I thought that when `25` is used, an error might occur.
- I think that your script of `function (e, r) {if (e) {console.log(e);} else {console.log(r.data);}}` is for googleapis of Node.js. So I modified this to Javascript.

  - About `Its Not Work.`, I thought that the reason might be this. Because in your script, no response is returned.

#### Modified script:

```
function makeApiCall() {
  var updateObject = {
    documentId: 'My-Document-Id',
    resource: {
      requests: [{
        insertText: {
          text: "Sameer Bayani",
          location: {
            index: 1, // Modified
          },
        },
      }],
    },
  };
  gapi.client.docs.documents.batchUpdate(updateObject)
  .then(function(res) { // Modified
    console.log(res);
  },function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that you have already used Google Docs API by Javascript. When the authorization of your script works, above modified script works. If the errors related to authorization and Docs API occur, please confirm about the script and whether Docs API is enabled.
- In order to test this script, I used `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents` as the scope.

#### Reference:

- [Browser Quickstart for Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/js)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Sameer Bayani Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.